# Gemfile.lock not checked in - Heroku × 45807

Tags: heroku, ecma262, gemfile

Get the same problem as in (7) and tried all the possible answers but still couldnt get any headway. I wish you could be of help (bearing in mind that i am a newbie please). Here is the description of the problem @ hand:
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 403 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Windows Gemfile.lock detected, ignoring it.
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * source: source at vendor/engines
       * source: git://github.com/Dougui/refinerycms-portfolio.git (at master)
       * source: rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
       * sqlite3
       * rake (= 0.8.7)
       * refinerycms (~> 1.0.3)
       * refinerycms-i18n (~> 1.0.0)
       * fog
       * refinerycms-portfolio
       * refinerycms-geolocations (= 1.0)
       * nokogiri

       You have changed in the Gemfile:
       * refinerycms-portfolio from `git://github.com/Dougui/refinerycms-portfol
io.git (at master)` to `no specified source`
       * refinerycms-geolocations from `source at vendor/engines` to `no specifi
ed source`
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

To git@heroku.com:vivid-rain-722.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:vivid-rain-722.git'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, your `gemfile.lock` is not the same as the one in repository.
Try doing the following steps.

```
bundle install
git add gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Add gemfile.lock"
git push heroku master
```